# LND funding transaction stuck in mempool due to low fees

Tags: lightning-network-daemon, ln-opening-channels, child-pays-for-parent, lncli, bumpfee

I have a funding transaction stuck in mempool due to low fees. Searchng around I have find that there is *"BumpFee"* wallet option to push your transaction. i have tried in this way:

**~$ lncli wallet bumpfee [Channel_point] --sat_per_byte 150**

**>[lncli] rpc error: code = Unknown desc = the passed output doesn't belong to the wallet**

When type:

**~ $ lncli pendingchannels**

i can see the transaction waiting for confirmation, but when type:

**~$ lncli wallet pendingsweeps**

> {
>                 "pending_sweeps": []
>     }

there arent.
The transaction is still present when type:

**~ $ lncli listchaintxns**

Someone can  try to explain or have had similar behaviour?
Don’t found so much useful stuff in Github

*https://github.com/lightningnetwork/lnd/blob/master/lnrpc/walletrpc/walletkit.proto*

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem whit CPFP (children pay for parent).

I used the  unconfirmed change of the fund TX stuck in mempool to open a new channel.

At the time of broadcasting TX the median fee is around 150sat/vb, so i chose to slight increase at 200 sat to ensure good probability to push the first fund tx and the second one in the next block avaible.

Comment: Can you please give me the command using the fund TX stuck in mempool to open a new channel?
When I do a new 'lncli openchannel' I cannot specify the fund TX stuck in mempool. I tried it with the same Public Key and the same local-amt but instead a new channel was opened to this Node. The old unconfirmed transaction still stuck on the mempool. Again: Can you please post how the command TX stuck in mempool to open a new channel looks like? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I got a sweep TX (from a force closed channel) stuck, also due to low fees. This answer is inspired by [OPs answer](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/96019/99815).

I got it working with:

```
lncli openchannel \
--sat_per_byte=${fees per byte for the funding transaction of the new channel} \
--min_confs=0 \
${remote nodes id} \
${local amount}
```

The `--min_confs=0` part is the important bit, it allows lnd to use unconfirmed TXes for the funding, but that doesn't mean it will use that particular unconfirmed TX.

---

[bos](https://github.com/alexbosworth/balanceofsatoshis) seems to have an option for specifying UTXOs with their `bos fund --utxo ${utxo}` command. (haven't tested that)

`bos fund` can be used with other commands for example `bos open` to open (multiple) channels as described [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/lightningnetwork/comments/m627ms/how_to_batch_open_multiple_channels_at_once_with/gr5bnla/?context=3).